# makefile tries to compile itself

Tags: c, macos, makefile, compilation

Can someone help to solve this problem.
When I try to do make my makefile does this.

```
`echo ./src/main.c
./src/main.c
gcc -c -g -Iinclude src/main.c
gcc   Makefile.o   -o Makefile
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Makefile.o'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [Makefile] Error 1`
```

actually all I have in my directory is:
a makefile named: Makefile.
three empty folders named :doc include and obj.
And one folder named src with main.c inside.

my Makefile looks is:

```
CC := gcc
HEADERS := -Iinclude
C_SOURCES := $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
O_SOURCES := ./obj
OBJ := $(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o))
C_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Werror
B_FLAGS := -c -g


main:$(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $^
    mv $^ $(O_SOURCES)
    mkdir -p bin
    mv main ./bin


%.o:$(C_SOURCES)
    echo $(C_SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(B_FLAGS) $(HEADERS) $^

depend:
    makedepend $(HEADERS) $(C_SOURCES)

tar:
    tar -Jcf b-GoL-$(TAG).tar.xz Makefile $(C_SOURCES) $(HEADERS)

clean :
    @clear
    rm -rf bin $(O_SOURCES)/$(OBJ) b-GoL-$(TAG).tar.xz
```

Thanks to everybody who will try to help me in my journey

Comment: Just a wild guess - add a space after the colon before prerequisites: `%.o: $(C_SOURCES)` (same for `main` target)

Comment: It still not work but thanks

Comment: How about adding `echo $^`?

Comment: I do not reproduce.  How are you launching make?

Comment: I just write make that's all

Comment: where do you want me to add echo $^ ?

Comment: That's weird. Check that you `make` is not an alias for something different. Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am actually using macOS Catalina v10.15.1.

Comment: I did make -d to see what is happening so my makefile try to call methods name makefile to I think that's why it's not actually working but I never had this problem before on ubuntu

Comment: Ok so I finally found a solution for the problem I had. So if I understand everything my make command was trying to use my Makefile file and used the name of my Makefile as the first "argument" if I can say so I had to add a .PHONY: Makefile at the end of my Makefile. First time I see this problem ans this kind of solution but that work for the moment thank everyone.

Comment: Please tell us what was the problem. You can do it as an answer if you think it worth it.

Comment: The probleme was while I try to use make command my makefile tried to creat a .o file with itself and it make every fonction crash in the makefile

Comment: Last time I looked the default `make` on Mac OS was BSD make, not GNU make. And you're using GNU make features.

Comment: Similarly the actual compiler on that platform is `clang` (which you can see from the error message), and gcc is just an alias. Might as well tell the Makefile what your compiler *really* is.

Comment: My bad I didn't knew that Mac OS use BSD make I juste changed computer. I don't think the problem came from the fact I use gcc or clang because in both case it didn't worked but I think the make command on Mac is different than GNU make.

Comment: Personallky I add the GNU tool chain on my mac using `homebrew` as part of my basic set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce this behavior with your Makefile and I was quite surprised because I never saw this before. It took a moment to find the reason.

Make has several built-in rules, including `%:%.o`. And one of its internal dependencies to be watched is the Makefile itself. And because you have a generic rule defining a dependency `%.o:$(C_SOURCES)` Make constructs a path from your C sources to `Makefile`.

That's why it wants to generate `Makefile` from `Makefile.o` which it thinks was built from your sources.

Change your compile rule into

```
$(OBJ):%.o:src/%.c
```

and you'll not only limit this rule to your object files only, but also assigns each source to its object file.

Your rule `%.o:$(C_SOURCES)` is wrong. It defines every single object file to be dependent of *all* of your sources. The recipe of this rule will additionally get *all* source files on its command line.

Some hints: Use make's options to see what it thinks.

- `-n` just prints the commands but does *not* execute them. This is not true for commands rebuilding the Makefile; these are executed always, IIRC.
- `-d` prints a lot of debugging stuff, including decisions *why* some files are considered for building.
- `-p` prints make's rules and recipes. Well, it's quite hard to read, but worth in such difficult situations.

Comment: And I now know why I couldn't reproduce.  My Makefile was dated after the source files and thus make didn't try to remake it.

Comment: Well you solution looks way better than mine thanks for everything.

Comment: @AProgrammer :-D Yes, I fell in that trap, too. And I wondered why the effect worked just once: I edited the Makefile in between without touching `main.c`.

Comment: I'll delete my answer because mine is wrong thanks again.